# Allow user from another PC to connect to my localhost website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, localhost

I am running a website on localhost:portnumber on visual studio 2005, and want to allow another person to connect to it from another PC. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following this article and see if it works

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2009/09/03/accessing-the-visual-studio-asp-net-development-server-from-iphone.aspx

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do, test the site on my iPad.

Comment: The link now gives just a 404

Comment: Archive version: https://web.archive.org/web/20090922202432/http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2009/09/03/accessing-the-visual-studio-asp-net-development-server-from-iphone.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Possible, yes.

You will need an ip address that is accessible from that other machine.

Your firewall will need to allow the appropriate port to be open (typically 80).

If you want them to use a DNS name, that DNS name must be pointed to your IP.  And, again, it must be externally accessible.

Now, if the client is NOT on your local network, then the IP will have to be a public one that is routed to your machine.  Depending on where you are (corporate, etc) there may be other firewalls in place to prevent this.  In this case contact your local network admin.

Comment: How do I get port 80 to connect to my local port number for the VS project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible for only for testing purposes first you need to install IIS and get dynamic DNS to allow user to connect to your computer (Using your Dynamic IP) Check [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/) , [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) point this dynamic host to your IIS website, Bindings settings

Comment: Assuming he's not behind a firewall or router, which is most likely the case nowadays.

Comment: do you really need a dynamic DNS? or can't you just check your ip everytime you want someone to connect?

Comment: No need for Dynamic DNS, but its easier instead of every time ask for ip. And also port using should be forwarded if he is behind router/firewall

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  You need to do two things:

1) Open that "portnumber" for incoming connections through your windows firewall (and any other firewall you may be running).

2) Set up your router to allow incoming connections on that "portnumber" and route those connections to your local computer's IP Address.

That should do it. Be aware that doing this opens up your computer to be hacked if you are not careful.